# xdmp.email() function is returning "null"

Tags: javascript, linux, marklogic

I am trying to send an email using `xdmp.email()` function but it is returning `null`

```
var from = {"name":"Administrator", "address":"anythingyouwant@cha.rbxd.ds"};
var address1 = {"address":"harmanjotsingh1997@gmail.com"};
var contentType = "text"
var message = {"from":from,
               "to":address1,
               "subject":"Test email from ML Server",
               "content":"hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii"
               };
xdmp.email(message);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `xdmp.email()` method returns `null`. This is documented:

https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.email

```
xdmp.email(
   $message as Object,
   [$options as Object?]
) as null
```

However, just because the method returns `null` doesn't mean that it won't send the email.

Also noted in the documentation for this method:

> A valid SMTP Relay must be configured in the Groups page of the Admin Interface for the email to be sent.

If there is an issue sending the email, it should throw an [XDMP-MAIL exception](https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/messages/XDMP-en/XDMP-MAIL)

Have you verified whether the email was sent, or are you trying to figure out why it might not have been sent and hoping that it would return some sort of error message?